# MongoDB - how to insert a location into collection

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb

I am looking a way to insert a location value to a collection in MongoDB. I am using MongoDB JAVA driver. Unfortunately I am not able to do so.

The collection is indexed properly. The issue here is the collection accepts the location in the form of an array which holds double value. But I am not sure whether there is a way to send an array directly since only the reference of the array is sent and not the actual content.

The code is below 
    double latLong[] = {124.6682391, -17.8978304};
    final BasicDBObject loc = new BasicDBObject();
    loc.put("type","Point");
    loc.put("coordinates", latLong);

```
jsonObject.put("location", loc);
```

After adding when I tried printing it I am getting the following output.

```
"location" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : "[D@53e21fa6"}
```

This results in "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:" error.

I tried sending location as an arraylist. But this again stores the value as

```
"location" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : "[144.6682362, -37.8978302]"}
```

But not as

```
"location" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : [144.6682362, -37.8978302]}
```

This again results in "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:" error.

Also tried Arrays.toString((latLong))

This resulted in

```
" location" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : "[144.6682362, -37.8978302]"}
```

Hence same error again.

The below URL says that this cannot be accomplished.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/TUjAxag6yT4

But still some part of my brain says there should be a way.

Any idea how to add a location object ( which is an array holding double value) to the JSON object and thereby to the collection by converting the JSON object to a DBObject?

I am not looking for  a POJO library since I want to stick to my native code.  If nothing can be done, I may jump to a POJO library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create jsonarray of co-ordinates and then put it in jsonObject. Try something like this:

```
        double latLong[] = {124.6682391, -17.8978304};
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(latLong);
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject().put("type", "point");
        jobj.put("coordinates", jsonArray);

        // below  jsonObject_loc contains the jsonobject as you want..
        JSONObject jsonObject_loc = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject_loc.put("loc", jobj);
        System.out.println(jsonObject_loc);

       // but you have to store jobj in db as your query already has 'loc' object
        BasicDBObject loc = new BasicDBObject();
        loc.put("loc", jobj.toString());
```

The JSON Library used for the above code is : [java-json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(latLong); This throws an error "The constructor JSONArray(double[]) is undefined"

Comment: are you passing the same latLong as defined above??

Comment: double latLong[] = {Double.parseDouble(strLongitude), Double.parseDouble(strLatitude)};
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
   jsonArray.put(latLong);   
         JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject().put("type", "point");
         jobj.put("coordinates", jsonArray);
         jsonObject.remove("location");
         jsonObject.put("location", jobj);
         System.out.println(jsonObject);   Have tried this code. But still having the same issue. It is passing the location and not the actual value. Any directions?

Comment: what is the value of "strLongitude" and  "strLatitude" in above code??

Comment: Yes. Used the latLong[] provided by you. Thanks for your speedy reply. The result in println is "location":{"type":"point","coordinates":["[D@fed6a53"]}}

Comment: what is the value of strLongitude??

Comment: Longitude is 144.6682362, Latitude is -37.8978302

Comment: double latLong[] = {144.6682362, -37.8978302};JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(latLong); use this exactly, in your example you have used: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(); jsonArray.put(latLong);

Comment: I intitially used double latLong[] = {144.6682362, -37.8978302};
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(latLong); I was getting an error in code "The constructor JSONArray(double[]) is undefined". Are you getting any errors when you use it? Let me know if I am missing anything here

Comment: no i am not getting any error, which  json library you are using , check your imports and let me know?

Comment: I am using JAX-RS and while hovering over JSONObject I am getting "org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject"

Comment: use java -json , org.json.JSONArray and org.json.JSONObject, these are the imports. directly replace the imports to check if library is already there or not?

Comment: Thanks. I fell into lot more issues. I downloaded the jar from https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/detail?name=org.json-20120521.jar&can=2&q=. But when running it I am getting "SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Jersey REST Service
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONArray"

Comment: Could you please provide me the correct place to get the jar from. Thanks once again for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks.I believe I am able to see the sunlight. Please be online for a moment.

Comment: Yes. No words to describe my happiness. It is working fine. The JSON library did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TimothyRajan have edited the answer with the mention of json library.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old, but newly i faced similar issue and found easy way of doing it using mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar downloaded from [sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.3/mongo-java-driver-2.13.3.jar)
The one possibility is directly to put the coordinates in a BasicDBObject like here:

```
double latLong[]= {124.6682391, -17.8978304};
BasicDBObject loc1= new BasicDBObject("location", 
                     new BasicDBObject("type", "Point")
                    .append("coordinates", latLong));

System.out.println("DEBUG: loc1 is: " + loc1.toString());
```

The result is:

```
DEBUG: loc1 is: { "location" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : [ 124.6682391 , -17.8978304]}}
```

Another possibility which i found even better is to put BasicDBList like here:

```
BasicDBList coords= new BasicDBList();
coords.add(Double.valueOf(124.6682391));
coords.add(Double.valueOf(-17.8978304));
BasicDBObject loc2= new BasicDBObject("location", 
    new BasicDBObject("type", "Point")
   .append("coordinates", (latLong)));

System.out.println("DEBUG: loc2 is: " + loc2.toString());
```

The result is again:

```
DEBUG: loc2 is: { "location" : { "type" : "Point" , "coordinates" : [ 124.6682391 , -17.8978304]}}
```